# Getting the maximum width of a textfield in Silk4J

Tags: java, sap-gui, silktest

In a previous version of our application there was a [SAP GUI SapTextField](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSapTextFieldClass_ref.html) that allowed too long input. I'd now like to write a test that ensures the maximum input length of the textfield is limited.

Unfortunately I could not find a way to determine the width of the textfield in characters. The [`getWidth()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FWidthPropertySapComponent_ref.html) method returns the width in pixels, not characters.

I know that using `setText()` causes a `RuntimeException` when the text is too long for the textfield, but using that as an indicator is dangerous since `RuntimeException` is used for many other problems as well.

Is there a way to determine the maximum width of a SAP GUI textfield in Silk4J?

Code that I have today:

```
try 
{
    SapTextField textfield = desktop.<SapTextField>find("...");
    textfield.setText("1234567");
    fail("The textbox should be limited to 6 characters");
}
catch(RuntimeException re)
{
    // TODO: find a more reliable way of detecting this
}
```

Comment: Can you please tag your question with the language you are using (which I assume is either C# or VB from the documentation link you provided).  Also, give us the code for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the question is tagged Java, the term Silk4J is in the question title and text. The link refers to .NET since the Java documentation is not online. I have added code.